# how to open modal dialog within Repeater control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a scrolling photo gallery in home page where there is some message in the bottom photo gallery it display only 120 character and there is a link says "continue reading" when I clicked on that link a modal dialog should be opened and it displays message from database.
These photos are continues moving and the photos are coming from database so that for that functionality I am using repeater. Photos are scrolling successfully but messages are not displayed.

I am little bit confusing how to do this so please help me.Thanks in advance..!

Comment: what you have tried so far? a simple google search can give you a hundreds of results.

Comment: I have already tried but i can't get proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a model popup extender from ajax control toolkit 
   http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx
2. Or you can make a modal popup your own with simple css and javascript (jquery)
3. Try with jquery ui 
   http://jqueryui.com/dialog/